# How can I log the SSL layer with the Apache HTTP server classes

Tags: java, http, ssl, https, apache-httpcomponents

I have a custom application that is using httpcomponents-core-4.2.4 and the SSLContext/SSLEngine with Oracle JDK to enable https.

It works fine in Windows/OSX environments.

However, it does not work in Ubuntu 12.04 with OpenJDK.

How can I enable logging for the HTTP components or the SSL classes, since they do not provide anything to log4j logs, although the client side httpcomponents do.

I found that there is an internal [Debug instance in SSLEngineImpl](https://bitbucket.org/jwalton/jdk/src/0c65618b5ae189882a5b0716a83d958d78a93edc/src/share/classes/sun/security/ssl/SSLEngineImpl.java), but how do I enable it?

Comment: *What* 'Apache HTTP server classes'? You seem to be actually asking about the *Oracle,* *Java,* *client* classes, I.e. JSSE, to me.

Comment: Yes you are right. I was not sure what is actually involved and what is the role of each in this scenario. Therefore I mentioned httpcomponents-core and SSL-classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, found it out. I guess I had to write the question to really get onto it. This does it:

```
java -Djavax.net.debug=all
```

The full guide is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#Debug)